# Is it possible to create child themes using the Wordpress Dashboard?

Tags: themes, child-theme, dashboard

I've been looking into creating a child theme in which I can make changes to my theme, but all the tutorials I can find assume that you're working with a local  Wordpress installation, and explain how to create the necessary folders and files in a file manager like Windows Explorer.

Is it possible to create a child theme from within the Wordpress.org dashboard itself?

Answer (score 3):

You will achieve this in two steps:

- uploading minimal files at **yourdomain.com/wp-admin/themes.php**
- editing child theme at **yourdomain.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php**

The theme that you upload to your site via the admin console must contain three files. They will end up in your server's filesystem like this:

`/wp-content/themes/parentname-child/functions.php`
`/wp-content/themes/parentname-child/screenshot.png`
`/wp-content/themes/parentname-child/style.css`

When uploading, `functions.php` can be empty, but `style.css` must contain the required header comment at the very top of the file. While not strictly mandatory, `screenshot.png` improves the user experience by giving the theme a thumbnail in the console. Once the child theme validates, it will show up in in your WordPress Theme Editor (e.g. yourdomain.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php) where you can edit within the web console.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's is it possible to create chile theme within admin dashboard. anyway, screenshot is not required as mandatory. mandatory is the style.css and index.php

Comment: I interpret 'creating' not just as instantiating a file in the filesystem, but adding and editing the content of the files. My answer addresses this interpretation. Yes, screenshot might not be necessary, but it improves user experience in the admin console.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the necessary files and folders on your local machine, zip them up, and then upload them as a new theme from the "Add New Theme" screen: https://wordpress-install.test/wp-admin/theme-install.php

Click on the Upload Theme button next to the page title.